# Can we Extend Highstocks features to Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a feature where we have to compare multiple series.  I have implemented the same with Highcharts but when I looked at [highstocks compare](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare) i was pretty much impressed by the way it is doing.  Can we extend the same features in Highcharts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible to extend, but you can do the same using [tooltip formatter](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#tooltip--formatter).

Comment: Thanks the tooltip [crosshairs](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/crosshairs-x/) and [pointformat](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/pointformat/) helped me achieve the same. These features are  landing similar to [compare](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare) of highstocks. I wanted to map the series properly and was looking for same.. and it helped!

Comment: tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>',
            valueSuffix: ' cm',
            shared: true,
            crosshairs: true
        },

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tooltip formatter to create a tooltip with the format

series.name: series.values[x]  for point x, and loop that over each series in the chart.  That should create the effect you want.

Highstock is also an extension of highcharts, and you should be able to swap it in for your highcharts code without any compatibility issues if you're willing to pay extra to use it or are using it for non-commercial purposes.